# How can I get an image src value using a directive in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-directive

As from the title, I'd like to understand how to get an image src value using a directory

Directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appLazyImage]',
})
export class LazyImageDirective implements OnInit {

    @HostBinding('src') public src: string;
    @Input() private appLazyImage: string;

    constructor() {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        //this.src is undefined
        console.log(this.appLazyImage, this.src);
    }

}
```

Html:

```
<img [appLazyImage]="'test'" class="product-content-image__img" [src]="{{url}}" alt="{{alt}}" title="{{title}}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ElementRef Service to get Src attribute

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSrc]'
})
export class SrcDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.src);
  }

}
```

Comment: @Chellappan What do you mean? Your example doesn't have a directive.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nativeElement` to get the attribute values.

```
 constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
    let src = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('src'); 
  }
```